# Excel Formula to list non #N/A data's header in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula specifically (user does not want vba coded), that will find the headers in each row that does not contain #N/A.

Here's an example
Clients Owed
[image]

I want a formula in the "Clients Owed" column that will give me the results like what is in the first 2 rows where it lists the clients in that row that does not contain #N/A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment to [Scott Craner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49734347/9290986), you do not have Office 365, so you can't use `CONCAT` or `TEXTJOIN`.  If you know *exactly* how many clients you have, then you can hard-code your concatenation with `IF` statements.  The following will work for clients in columns `D`/`E`/`F`/`G`:

```
=MID(IF(ISERROR($D2),", " & $D$1,"") & IF(ISERROR($E2),", " & $E$1,"") & IF(ISERROR($F2),", " & $F$1,"") & IF(ISERROR($G2),", " & $G$1,""), 3, 1E+9)
```

The more client columns you have, the longer the formula gets.

Comment: That worked great! I just needed to add NOT. Thank you. This will save a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Use TEXTJOIN() as an array:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(NOT(ISERROR($C2:$F2)),$C$1:$F$1,""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

This formula only works if the user has office 365 Excel.  If the user does not have Office 365 Excel then they will need vba or helper columns.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately we have Professional Pro Plus 2016. Do you have an idea for helper columns that you mentioned?